# ForEach -parallel, how to return/save output to an array

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell

Perhaps, someone could help me with an issue a have. I want to speed up script processing time and rewrite it in parallel in PS core or workflow.

For now, I'm struggling with saving the output to an array inside parallel foreach loop.
Right here I'm going through each storage account and saving only with blobs into `$StrgAccsObj`. After I want to use this array @() in the next loop but after this part, there is nothing inside. My question how can I save it into an array?

```
$strgAccs | ForEach-Object -parallel{
    Write-Output "Checking storage $($_.StorageAccountName)"
    if ($_.Kind -eq "BlobStorage"){Write-Host "BlobStorage,- skipping"; $StrgAccsObj += $_; continue;}
    $tables = Get-AzStorageTable -Context $_.Context
    $queues = Get-AzStorageQueue -Context $_.Context
    $shares = Get-AzStorageShare -Context $_.Context
    if ($tables) {Write-Host "Stopping, SA is actual"; continue;}
    if ($queues) {Write-Host "Stopping, SA is actual"; continue;}
    if ($shares) {Write-Host "Stopping, SA is actual"; continue;}
    else {Write-Host "Saving SA to blob check list"; $StrgAccsObj += $_}
}
```

Thanks very much in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could assign the output from your pipeline to a variable:

```
$output = $strgAccs | ForEach-Object -parallel{
    Write-Host "Checking storage $($_.StorageAccountName)"
    if ($_.Kind -eq "BlobStorage"){
        Write-Host "BlobStorage,- skipping"

        # Output
        $_

        # Next
        continue
    }

    $tables = Get-AzStorageTable -Context $_.Context
    $queues = Get-AzStorageQueue -Context $_.Context
    $shares = Get-AzStorageShare -Context $_.Context
    if ($tables) {
        Write-Host "Stopping, SA is actual"; continue
    }
    if ($queues) {
        Write-Host "Stopping, SA is actual"; continue
    }
    if ($shares) {
        Write-Host "Stopping, SA is actual"; continue
    }

    Write-Host "Saving SA to blob check list"
    
    # Output
    $_
}
```

Now `$output` contains the values that would have otherwise been added to `$StrgAccsObj`

Comment: `ForEach-Object -Parallel` might be magic but it's still a pipeline-optimized cmdlet and behaves as such ;-)

Comment: Is there a solution if I need two diff outputs from the loop?

Comment: Output `[pscustomobject]@{ Kind = 'MyOutputKind'; Value = $_ }` instead of `$_`, then split the output into two after the fact with `$myOutput,$otherOutput = $output.Where({$_.Kind -eq 'MyOutputKind'}, 'Split')`